# Are old AC transformers dangerous?

Tags: transformer

Is an AC transformer in a desk light from the 1970s a significant risk to keep using in your home when it comes to fire safety? It was already broken in the first place so this is a theoretical question. When it was still working a few years back, I could hear the mains hum coming from it. My annoyance with that caused me to neglect the lamp. Picture of the transformer in question below:

[image: 1970s AC transformer]

Comment: Anything is a risk. Even new transformers, or transformerless supplies, or switch mode power supplies. These could start a fire at any time, and every now and then it does happen even if they mostly don't start fires. Normally there are fuses and thermal fuses to cut power when something goes wrong, but if the thermal fuse and fuse are also faulty then it may result in fire. So if it is or isn't a significant risk mostly depends on your definition of significant.

Comment: See added paper link and abstract in my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's properly designed (the original lamp-transformer system) it won't be much of a fire hazard or shock hazard. A 1970s lamp probably is made of metal, so even if the transformer failed it would be unlikely to be able to start a fire- the winding or a fuse (internal or external to the transformer) will fail first.

The transformer you show is of split-bobbin design which provides a lot of insulator between primary and secondary windings (at the expense of some performance).

A hum or buzz from the transformer (typically at 100 or 120Hz depending on your mains frequency) isn't typically a sign of impending doom, it's just a loose lamination or something similar moving from the magnetic field, which does not noticeably affect the transformer operation.

The biggest indications of safety are UL/CSA or similar markings, and the cord and housing being in good condition. Also, if the bulb is a halogen type, the glass envelope has to get to a very high temperature compared to conventional incandescent lamps (>500°C) in order for the cycle to work- hot enough to perhaps ignite something. As we all may expect from Ray Bradbury's classic dystopian novel title, paper can ignite at 233°C. There should be protective glass preventing any contact with potentially flammable materials even if the lamp is knocked over by a pet or whatever. That's a safety requirement that may not have existed when the lamp was manufactured, and [quite a few fires](https://www.cpsc.gov/Newsroom/News-Releases/1996/CPSC-Issues-Warning-on-Tubular-Halogen-Bulbs) happened before it was codified if memory serves.

Once you remove the transformer from the product it could be more dangerous since a failure might not be contained by a metal housing. Or maybe you could drop it on your foot. Or the mains wiring might not be properly insulated or fused. Lots of ways to make it unsafe.

In any case, nothing is 100% safe. Inside an unmodified and relatively modern (1970s) safety-agency approved product it should be relatively safe.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention the bulb, which I was the most scared of: it was a halogen bulb without protective glass. I did not really had a doubt that part is indeed unsafe. The lamp is an Artemide Tizio, which can be knocked over by design: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizio

Comment: *As we all may expect from Ray Bradbury's classic dystopian novel title, paper can ignite at 233°C* Was "Fahrenheit 451" sold as "Celsius 233" outside the US?

Comment: Love that "can be knocked over by design" phrase!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - Sadly not

Comment: @ScottishTapWater TBF, the novel predates the EU (and even the EEC Treaty of Rome, by a few years).

Comment: Where in the world is the mains frequency 100 or 120 Hz? I've only ever heard about 50 or 60 Hz...

Comment: @Sixtyfive Magnetic force is dependent on magnitude irrespective of polarity so the sound is at double mains frequency.

Answer (score 7):

As Spehro says - the transformer is likely to be safe.

**However:**  (and not what you asked about)

[The lamp itself](https://wiki2.org/en/Tizio) may be a fire hazard.
They say:

> There are no wires between the base and the lamp: the two parallel arms, connected with snap fasteners, conduct safe 12-volt electricity

The use of "snap fasteners" suggests that the current is transferred across use disconnectable connectors. There are numerous lamp designs which transfer energy along bare conductove metal arms or rods. The 12 VAC can be directly connected to. This is a potential but usually unrealised fire hazard. I have tried to produce fire from such lamps to see how likely this is in use. I could do so only with significant effort. So, in practice this aspect also seems "reasonably safe" - but still a hazard.

[image]

Here is a relevant paper.
Note that the mechanisms that allow very low ignition energy will often be absent in lamp use environments. But, not always.

[Low Voltage: The Incompetent Ignition Source - Dispelling the Myth](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ddd523267a1ae54e9d2cb96/t/611031724828f94c0f57fa78/1628451187303/foresite-low-voltage-the-incompetent-ignition-source.pdf)

- Abstract
  The present, widely held belief is that products powered by “low voltage” (typically less than 24V) electrical
  energy are incapable of starting fires since there exists an insufficient level of energy to produce sufficient
  heat and ignition. By analyzing commonly implemented electronic circuits found in a variety if household
  electronic devices, manufactured using standard wave solder or surface mount technology (SMT)
  processes, single point failures will be discussed and induced that demonstrate ignition at low voltages, or
  more precisely, low power levels. Through the application of a thoughtfully designed series of experiments,
  this paper will demonstrate that voltages as low as 3VDC and power levels in the 3W range or less, are
  entirely capable of igniting proximate fuel packages sufficient to produce sustained fire in a variety of
  electronic assemblies.

Comment: I had a desk lamp which worked that way in the 1990s, in the US, and it wasn't an antique. (It was from IKEA or Target, some respectable chain store.) So I can only assume that UL thinks it's safe enough.

Comment: @GlennWillen  The ones I have "played with" were also "modernish". Regardless of what UL may think [ ! :-) ] it is possible to start a fire with them. I'd be very surprised if at least a few accidental fires had not been started by them. || There is a paper on the usually unseen hazards of low voltage as an unreliable fire initiator. I\ll see if I can find it.  || I had trouble starting a fire with one :-).

Comment: @GlennWillen Paper link and abstract added

Comment: Even if you get a 3V3 trace intended to carry 1A to burn up on an FR4 PCB, for that relatively short-lived and small flame to set the rest of the device, and then the area surrounding the device, on fire, the device's enclosure must have contained things that were really not supposed to have been there in the first place.

Comment: @Sixtyfive In the context of this question AC 12V is on the 2 metal rails supporting the lamp. In this case it's exposed at the clickapart connectors & maybe also on the rails proper. On many lamps the rails are bare conductors (usually chrome plated steel) and you can draw full power from the surfaces. If  the lamp falls over, droops down or the conductors are just pressed against something else they MAY cause a fire. || Re "not supposed to have been there" --> Murphy achieves many results using things out of place. Major disasters often need about 4+ impossible things to happen. They do :-(

Comment: I was referring to the paper you linked, Russell, which you also quoted as demonstrating ignition from 3VDC@1-ish amps. Whether 3 or 12, while it may be easy to set a PCB or perhaps a wire's isolation material on fire, after that if the fire finds no food, it will simply die. Of course, a PCB inside of an enclosure is different from a lamp on a desk. But yeah, Murphy :-) :-(

Comment: @Sixtyfive Yes. I did manage to make fire with a lamp with bare rods but it was hard to do. I guess UL also found it hard. However, not impossible. Murphy can work in inverse ratio to desire to achieve :-). (As I know you will know).

Comment: Oh I do know. But sometimes we're way ahead of him. As a kid I used to buy 10000uF electrolytics the size of soda cans just to hook them up to the mains (on a long extension cord and outside the house, in a trash can). Oh the joy! :)

Comment: @Sixtyfive Comments shouldn't  be used for ... oh OK ... : Unmarked untested metal can TO26 transistors from the UK (I'm in NZ). Long lab bench with multiple mains outlets. Turn off bench main switch. Insert leads between P & N. Hide beside end of bench. All clear! "Fire In the hole".  Turn on main switch. Joyous eruption of flame and smoke. Broadside of transistor cans flies down the lab. Power off. Pull out fused in leads. Reload. Repeat. One day I was pulling out a dud transistor that had not fired. Felt warmth on face. Averted gaze. Boom. Missed ! Hmm - power hadn't been turned off :-) :-(

Answer (score 4):

Old transformers can contain [poly-chlorinated biphenyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychlorinated_biphenyl) (PCBs, not to be confused with Printed Circuit Boards) which are highly carcinogenic.

However this is more relevant to utility-size transformers which have liquid cooling, rather than small transformers used in domestic appliances.  But if the transformer has any kind of oil in it (even sealed inside) then there is a risk the oil may contain PCBs.

Comment: Fluorescent ballasts too. That's why in LED conversions they say to leave the ballast in the fixture, they don't want to be responsible for telling you to throw a PCB ballast in the trash. I say if the ballast is labeled non-PCB, give it to your poor friend who strips copper out of things, or if it's an electronic ballast dispose of it like any other electronics.

Answer (score 3):

All electrical transformers are AC. That's how they work. The buzzing should be harmless, unless there is a short circuit somewhere. But all non potted transformers produce some sound, much in the way a loudspeaker does. It's the interaction of the current flowing through the coils causing some minor movement in the coil an/or the laminations. Your local electricity substation also hums, when it's working perfectly well, if you listen carefully.

But to make it much safer, put that transformer into a suitable enclosure, preferably with ventilation, so that nobody can touch any high voltage terminals or wiring. It's also good practice to add a suitable fuse to protect from sustained overload currents.

Comment: *All electrical transformers are AC* - I hope the OP meant "AC transformer" as in "AC mains power transformer", intending to distinguish it from a transformer for higher-frequency signals and/or lower voltages.  But yes, clunky terminology in the title.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was indeed what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### The UL listing assures the safety of the appliance

UL certifies the entire fixture as safe, including the use of that transformer in that manner in that enclosure with that wiring.

If you salvaged the transformer and are placing it to another use, all bets are off... unless you send several specimens with a check for $20,000 to UL to have your design UL Listed.

Or you could simply follow the UL standards (e.g. UL White Book) in your design choices, and feel assured that it is just as safe as if UL actually checked your work.  (true or not lol).

Depending on material condition, of course.  If you had a transformer whose health you were unsure of, you could certainly use a mega-ohmmeter to test (an ohmmeter with a test probe voltage of several hundred volts), and I suppose if it passes you could send it out to a friendly neighborhood motor shop for VPI treatment - that's placing the unit in a vat of epoxy, drawing vacuum followed by pressure to force the epoxy into all voids. That's good to reduce vibration. Or feel free to replace the transformer with a UR-Recognized electronic power supply, in a manner which UL would approve.